# How to fix Dual graphic card problem? Nvidia and Intel

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside with windows 8, but the problem is that the fan is constantly running and I believe the problem is that my nvidia card is always running.

My laptop has two graphic cards. 
Intel Graphics 3000 and Nvidia GT540m.

I would like to only use Intel card, and nvidia only during games and such.
if anything I’m okay with disabling nvidia card, because i can play games on windows 8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/), it manages switching between the two cards and turns off the Nvidia card when it's not in use. Use this [guide for Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).